# onMouseEnter active on all mapped elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple component in which I map through an array of objects and display a li element for each object:

```
const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);

return (
  <ResultList>
    { props.movieList.length === 0 ? (<NoResults>No results were found...</NoResults>) : (null)}
    { props.movieList.map(movie => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <li 
          key={movie.id}
          onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}>
          <p>
            <span>{movie.original_title}</span>
          </p>
          {isHover && <AddMovieToDashboard />}
        </li>
      )
    })}
  </ResultList>
)
```

When I `onMouseEnter` on a li element I want to display another component `AddMovieToDashboard`. I've set this up by using the `useState` hook but as you might expect; this causes each li in the ul to display the `AddMovieToDashboard` component, and not just the one which is being hovered. I should probably use the unique `key` value from the li element somewhere but I can't find a good example how to do it.

Comment: Or have a variable in your movie list eg, `movie.isHover`. You'll need to have movie list in your state for that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about moving the items to a separate component so they can have their own state:

```
function ResultListItem(props) {
  const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li 
      key={props.movie.id}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <p>
        <span>{props.movie.original_title}</span>
      </p>
      {isHover && <AddMovieToDashboard />}
    </li>
  )
}

function Component(props) {
  return (
    <ResultList>
      { props.movieList.length === 0 ? (<NoResults>No results were found...</NoResults>) : (null) }
      { props.movieList.map(movie => {
          return (
            <ResultListItem movie={movie} />
          )
      })}
    </ResultList>
  )
}
```

Comment: It works, but this code feels complex. Thanks though, it works for now!